# How can I fix this infinite loop?

Tags: php, loops

I'm creating a website for a school, so they have it easier to complete orders they receive from students. I want to show what the students have already ordered, some kind of receit. But the table keeps looping, I don't find the answer myself.

I've asked programmers I knew for their help.

```
$sqlb = "SELECT tblOrderdetails.aantal, tblProducten.Productnaam, tblProducten.Prijs FROM tblOrders INNER JOIN tblOrderdetails ON tblOrders_OrderID = tblOrderdetails.tblOrders_OrderID INNER JOIN tblProducten ON tblProducten.ProductID = tblProducten.ProductID INNER JOIN tblLeerlingen ON tblLeerlingen_LeerlingID = tblOrders.tblLeerlingen_LeerlingID WHERE tblOrders.tblLeerlingen_LeerlingID = ".$id_session;

$result = mysqli_query($db,$sqlb);


?>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css" />
<table align = "center">
    <tr><th>Product</th><th>Aantal</th><th>Prijs</th></tr>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <?php
    $totaal = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $Aantal = ($row['aantal']);
        $totaalrij = ($row['Prijs'])*$Aantal;
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['Productnaam']."</td>
        <td>".$Aantal."</td>
        <td>".$totaalrij."</td>
        </tr>";
        $totaal = $totaal + $totaalrij;
    }
        $Totaalprijs = $totaal;
    ?>
```

I just want the table not to infinite loop itself, just once is enough for me.

Comment: There is no code here which can cause infinite loop

Comment: So why do I get an infinite loop? @u_mulder

Comment: Is it an infinite loop or is it just tasking longer than you are willing to wait?

Comment: What makes you think that you have infinite loop?

Comment: 1) There are more tables then one
2) There are multiple times the same product
3) I vard_dumped my Result and I get a never-ending string

Comment: i don't think its infinite your query is just returning a lot more results than you expected due to the joins

Comment: @NicholasSummers, it's actually looping, because I can see multiple tables

Comment: @tim I create my query inside of MySQL, so I know what it gets

Comment: @tim am I missing something? I've been avoiding php. while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) would just return the result from the mysqli_fetch_array function over and over and over, wouldn't it?

Comment: `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);` see how many results there actually are

Comment: That gives me back a number, but the number is bigger than the number of values in my database

Comment: because of the joins, you can get more results than any one table has rows. it can multiply table of 10 joined to table of 10 can have a result set of 100,

Comment: @tim I need those joins to know what to put inside of the table

Comment: I understand, but its either not the right join type or on the wrong values. Can't say which without seeing the table structure\data nad the desired output

Answer (score 0):

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) is your problem. try

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
```

and then

```
   foreach ($posts as $row) 
        { 
            foreach ($row as $element)
            {
                echo $element."<br>";
            }
        }
```

etc...

Highly Highly Highly recommend you do NOT echo your results like you are, it is ripe for XSS and other hacking attacks. use mysqli_real_escape_string and htmlspecialchars to protect yourself.

Comment: I do need a while loop, because every value is different, but in the same row.

Comment: in your while loop $result never changes so mysqli_fetch_array($result) will continue to return the same data over and over and over. I'm not sure what you mean by every value is different?

Comment: It means that inside of the query, you have like a table, in that table every value is different from the row above/under it

Comment: @MaartenGregoor I understand now. Edited my answer.

Comment: sorry not sure how to help you then